# How to access custom sign up field via AD Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm using https://graph.windows.net with credentials to access user data held within B2C AAD

```
 string graphRequest = $"https://graph.windows.net/mytenancy.onmicrosoft.com/users/" + UserName + "?api-version=1.6"
```

Where UserName is the ObjectID for that user

I create an object to handle the resulting data, e.g.

```
 displayName
 mail
```

I can deserialize the result and use the info from the profile

I've now edited the SignUpSignIn policy to add a custom field, a string, called StandID

When I view the profile through Postman, the name of that appears to be

```
  "extension_5295e65f1adc497186f72d63f5210d51_StandID": "E35"
```

However, I cannot seem to access the value via the same method, it comes back blank when I try and access it by the name given

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add an answer about what you did to solve the issue it'll help other people who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the answer came in two parts. The first was finding out how to identify the internal name it'd given - I did that by using Postman to show me the whole user profile as a json object

The second part was just a typo - because MSAL and ADAL are incompatible, yet I need to use both, my app is quite complex, and i was passing a value back from the API which I had the wrong receiver set up for in my app, once I realised that it all worked